# python 3.6.6 tkinter crashes in cmd, works in idle

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6, pythonw

I have a code block that works in idle, but not in cmd or double-clicking the file. For some reason, importing tkinter causes the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\main.pyw", line 20, in <module>
    import tkinter as Tkinter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    import re
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

no matter where I put the import, this happens, it happens on multiple computers, and the code works perfectly fine in idle. I am running python 3.6.6, on windows 10. i have already tried using `python -i main.py` in cmd and running the program with pythonw (as that's the interpreter that idle uses)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that my file, `enum.py`, was confusing tkinter, and once I renamed that file I haven't had any more problems